# Сайт без регистрации по почте, только через соцсети

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Хочу сделать на asp.net core с авторизацией, однако на сайте планируется авторизация только через соц. сети, а в типовом шаблоне (Authentication - Individual account) используется регистрация по почте и телефон.

Можно ли настройками как-то кастомизировать Identity, чтобы указать, что емейл не используется вообще? Или это не поддаётся кастомизции и нужно разрабатывать систему аутентификации с нуля?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755573/how-to-implement-oauth2-server-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Comment: Identity - это для хранения данных пользователей. Если вы их не храните, а запрашиваете - от Identity лучше отказаться, будет проще

Comment: @PavelMayorov а запрашиваемые хранить не надо?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин иногда совсем не надо. Иногда надо, но буквально 2-3 поля, Identity тут что из пушки по воробьям.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вам нужно называется OAuth2. Реализуется примерно [так](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/)